# Writing .shp file to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, databricks, geopandas

I try to write a geopandas dataframe (`df`) as a shape file to my s3 bucket (using databricks)

the S3 bucket is correctly mounted under `mnt/jk/Geo_data`

But

```
df.to_file('mnt/jk/Geo_data/shapefiles/Geometries.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

returns

```
 Failed to create file /databricks/driver/mnt/jk/Geo_data/shapefiles/Geometries.shp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The writing is done under the hood by the `fiona` library, and checking their github repo, it seems this will be possible in the upcoming 1.8 release: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/pull/426

Answer (score 1):

As geopandas is Python library, in databricks you need to prepend all paths with /dbfs/ . So your path should be "/dbfs/mnt/jk/Geo_data/shapefiles/Geometries.shp".